# Open multiple links in incognito with chrome.windows.create and chrome.tabs.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension for myself where i want to open multiple tabs in incognito for new sessions for my websites,

When the function is called it should open a new incognito window and open 4-5 tabs there, but currently the links are opened in the window where the chrome extension button has been clicked.

Current code:

```
    chrome.windows.create({focused: true, incognito: true }, function(win) {
          for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            array = links[i].href;
            chrome.tabs.create({ 
                url: array, 
                selected: true
            })
          }
    });
```

What should I change to make it open the new tabs in the incognito window?

Comment: @wOxxOm Works perfectly, can you post this as a answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the callback is invoked right after the window was [created](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onCreated) but before it was [focused](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onFocusChanged).

Specify the new window id in [chrome.tabs.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) options explicitly:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ 
    url: 'http://example.com', 
    windowId: win.id,
});
```

Comment: Actually, the `windows.create()` callback is invoked *after* the `windows` events.  The order is: `windows.onCreated` event, then multiple `tabs` events, then `windows.onFocusChanged` fires (sometimes twice), then the `windows.create()` callback. However, for many further operations you need to delay/wait for further events (e.g. a couple/few more `tabs.onUpdated` then a `tabs.onUpdated` with `status:'complete'`). There are no additional `windows` events after the `windows.create()` callback is fired.

Comment: But, that is not the issue here. In this case, the new window is, by design, not set to be the [current window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#current-window) (i.e. the window in which `tabs.create()` creates tabs when a windowId is not specified). Thus, the issue is not that that the "current window" hasn't yet changed, it is that it is designed such that opening a new window does not change the "current window" for the currently running code. Feel free to add this, or similar, info into your answer.

Comment: I'll recheck the source code first because the idea of sticky current window seems a bad API design choice to me.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to open several tabs in a newly created incognito window. Using the object received from creating the window to open the tabs with.

```
        chrome.windows.create({
            url: splashNodes[0].url,
            incognito: true,
        }, w => {
            console.log({w});
            for (let i = 1; i < splashNodes.length; i++) {
                chrome.tabs.create({
                    url: splashNodes[i].url,
                    windowId: w.id
                });
            }
        })
```

The window created as incognito didn't give anything back in the callback. chrome.windows.onCreated didn't fire either. Adding permission {"incognito":"split"} to the manifest as suggested by someone didn't help.

What solved my problem was when the user granted incognito permission to my extension (extension manager, details) though, as explained on https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings.